# How to print error message on popup box

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, popup

[image]

How to print error message( right on blue underline) on this popup box.
This popup box was created using bootstrap and my back end programming language is php

Comment: Show your code ?? for popup box.. just write your error reporting code below sign in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<strong>Success!</strong>
      My message 
</div>
```

Inside `<div class="modal-header"></div>`

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/fpek9tpd/)**

Answer (score 0):

Create one error div before username password.

```
<div id="error_msg" style="display:none">Invalid Id or Password</div>
```

after then use onClick event on sign in button and check validation and change style to display:block.

Comment: When i go for password validation popup box disappears could i use AJEX for username and password validation

Comment: Yes you need to add AJAX to check Id password validation on popup box.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
if(error condition){
      $("#error_msg").html("Invalid Id");
   }
    });
```

in popup box

```
<div id="error_msg"></div>
```